# issue in changing contents of file from lower case to upper case

Tags: c, file, fseek

I am trying to change the contents in a file from lower to upper case by using the code below. It got stuck in an infinite loop. What is the mistake here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error occured");
        exit(1);
    }
    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (islower(c))
        {
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc(toupper(c), fp);
        }
        //fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The programme is working fine if the commented line is uncommented.

If possible, please mention some good resource for knowing about fseek function in detail.

Comment: `char c;` ==> `int c;` ... and cast the argument to `islower()` and `toupper()` to `unsigned char`, ie: `islower((unsigned char)c)`

Comment: Unrelated, small inaccuracy: your title says you're trying to change from upper to lower case; the code clearly is attempting the opposite of that.

Comment: why does it got stuck in infinte loop ?

Comment: I like POSIX documentation: [`fopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html)"*When a file is opened with update mode ( '+' as the second or third character in the mode argument), ... the application shall ensure that **output is not directly followed by input** without an intervening call to fflush() or to a file positioning function (fseek(), fsetpos(), or rewind()), and **input is not directly followed by output** ...*"

Comment: @pmg The topics in documentation are difficult to understand . what should i do ?

Comment: My bad @Sai, sorry. I simply type function name (or header name) in the search box here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ The link above is an "internal" direct link

Comment: Why would you ever do this?  Open one file for reading, and a different file for writing.  When you are done, relink the files.  Actually attempting to update the file on the fly is a recipe for data corruption.  Friends don't let friends fseek.

Comment: You could/should put the commented out `fseek()` inside the body of the `if` statement.  It does no positive harm where it is, but it marginally slows things up.  Consider whether reading a block of, say, 1 KiB characters with `fread()` and then revising the buffer and writing it back with `fwrite()` would improve performance.  You could try bigger block sizes but the improvement will be fairly small after some threshold like 16 KiB — and if the files you're working with are small, there'll be no benefit whatsoever from block sizes bigger than the file size.

Comment: @William Pursell what do you mean by data corruption? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If your process is terminated unexpectedly (oom'd, or SIGINT'd, for example) before it is complete but after it has mutated portions of the file, your data will be partially processed.  Trying to figure out after the fact exactly which parts of the file have been processed and which have not is extremely difficult, if not impossible.  It may not be possible to reconstruct the original data.  Relinking can be done in such a way that it is always possible to recover.